# Select the first object that match condition or an inner object

Tags: c#, lambda, ienumerable

I have a class that contains an inner list of the same class, 
For example:

```
class Foo 
{
   string SearchId;
   List<Foo> GroupedPackages
}
```

I want to return the first "foo" instance that fits a condition, it can be in the main instance or in the inner List.

This is what I have so far - it is a bit ugly but it works:

```
Package = response.lst.Where(p => p.SearchId == SearchId || 
                                 (p.GroupedPackages != null &&
                                  p.GroupedPackages.Any(m => m.SearchId==SearchId)))
                                                   .FirstOrDefault();
if (Package != null)
{
    if (Package.SearchId != SearchId) 
    {

        Package = Package.GroupedPackages.FirstOrDefault(m => m.SearchId == SearchId);
    }
 }
```

Where "response.lst" is a List of foo and Package is foo.

I want if possible to do it in a one line lambda expression

Comment: The first one in a depth-first or breadth-first manner?

Comment: you might be looking for `SelectMany()`

Comment: You're currently only searching one level inside your structure. Do you intend to recursively look for the first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This selects the first `Foo` with the specified `SearchId` both on top level or in any of the `Foo` instances in `GroupedPackages`.

```
Package = response.lst
    .Concat(response.lst
        .Where(x => x.GroupedPackages != null)
        .SelectMany(x => x.GroupedPackages)
    )
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.SearchId == SearchId);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to flatten your list first before searching it.

Here's how to flatten the list:

```
Func<IEnumerable<Foo>, IEnumerable<Foo>> flatten = null;
flatten = fs =>
    from f0 in fs
    from f1 in new [] { f0, }.Concat(flatten(f0.GroupedPackages))
    select f1;
```

So, if I start with this structure:

```
var foos = new List<Foo>()
{
    new Foo()
    {
        SearchId = "Y",
        GroupedPackages = new List<Foo>()
        {
            new Foo() { SearchId = "X" },
            new Foo() { SearchId = "Z" },
            new Foo()
            {
                SearchId = "W",
                GroupedPackages = new List<Foo>()
                {
                    new Foo() { SearchId = "G" },
                    new Foo() { SearchId = "H" },
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I can flatten it like this:

```
flatten(foos);
```

The resulting enumerable is this:

[image: result]

So then it becomes simple to do this:

```
var result = flatten(foos).Where(f => f.SearchId == SearchId).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, it seems a bit too complex though

Comment: No, only one level deep

Comment: Ah, then, yes, it's more complicated than you need. I would suggest that you have the wrong structure then as your `Foo` class does allow multiple levels.

Comment: How would you build it to allow one level?

Comment: @ZivWeissman - Like this: `class Foo { string SearchId; } class FooRoot : Foo { List<Foo> GroupedPackages; }` - then the top level list is of type `FooRoot`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd first add a function to Foo that checks the condition:

```
class Foo {
  public bool FulfillsCondition(int searchId) {
     return this.SearchId==searchId;
  }
}
```

And then add a function to find itself or the children

```
class Foo {
  public Foo FindItemToFulfillCondition(int searchId) {
     if (this.FulfillsCondition) return this;
     return GroupedPackages.FirstOrDefault(p => p.FulfillsCondition);
  }
}
```

Then you can just

```
response.lst.Where(p => p.FindItemToFulfillCondition != null);
```

Comment: So if you need a different condition you have to write another function?

Comment: This is basically the same thing as I did, only with an extra method. It is a bit better but I was looking for something like Tim's answer

Comment: @Tim: Sure, you could also write a function and give an Expression&lt;T> instead of a fixed parameter, but the idea I wanted to express is to have the condition at one place and not write it again each for the parent and the child elements.